# Selecionar elementos aleatoriamente de um array sem repetir

Tags: javascript

Antes de tudo, procurei em diversos sites sobre esse problema e encontrei inúmeros exemplos, mas infelizmente nenhum desses exemplos funcionou na resolução do meu problema.
Enfim, estou desenvolvendo um quiz com base no jogo CS:GO, onde será mostrada uma foto e o usuário precisa acertar o nome da posição referente a foto (com base no jogo). 
Para isso, criei um array que possui objetos, que, por sua vez, possuem a imagem e o nome da posição que será mostrada. Por conta disso eu preciso que esses objetos com essas infos. sejam escolhidos randomicamente sem repetição, até o array não ter mais opções disponíveis.
Consegui chegar perto desse meu objetivo através desse código:

```js
const maps = [
  {
    mapName: "dust ii",
    positions: [
      {
        posicao: "fundo",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "escuro baixo",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "base tr",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "base ct",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    mapName: "mirage",
    positions: [
      {
        posicao: "fundomirage",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "escuro baixomirage",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
    ],
  },
];

let selectElementMap = document.getElementById("mapSelector");
let valueSelectedMap;
let positionAlreadyChosen = [];

function getSelectedValuesIndex() {
  valueSelectedMap =
    selectElementMap.options[selectElementMap.selectedIndex].value; // pegando o mapa através do "<select>" no html

  let positions = maps[valueSelectedMap].positions; // pega o array que contem o nome das posições e a imagem

  let randomArrayPos = Math.floor(
    Math.random() * maps[valueSelectedMap].positions.length
  );

  return (showPosition = positions[randomArrayPos].posicao); // pega uma posição aleatória do mapa
}

function basicLogic() {
  getSelectedValuesIndex();

  // verificar se a posição gerada já foi selecionada
  if (!positionAlreadyChosen.includes(showPosition)) { 
    positionAlreadyChosen.push(showPosition);
  }
  console.log(positionAlreadyChosen);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main class="content">
    <div class="selects-area">
      <select name="mapSelector" id="mapSelector">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um mapa</option>
        <option value="0">Dust II</option>
        <option value="1">Mirage</option>
        <option value="2">Cache</option>
        <!-- <option value="...">___</option> -->
      </select>
    </div>

    <button class="play" onclick="basicLogic();">Jogar</button>
  </main>
</div>
```

Logo, com esse código eu consigo o seguinte resultado quando clico para pegar os elementos random:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lQha.png]

Com tudo explicado, minha dúvida é a seguinte:
Há uma forma mais fácil de se fazer esse processo, sem que seja preciso clicar 9x (como no exemplo) para que todas as posições sejam escolhidas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Já pensou em apenas criar uma cópia do seu `array` e ordenar de forma aleatória?

```js
const desordenar = (arr) => {
  const copia = [...arr];

  for (let i = copia.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    let j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [copia[i], copia[j]] = [copia[j], copia[i]];
  }
  
  return copia;
};

const desordenado = desordenar(['fundo', 'base tr', 'base ct']);
console.log(desordenado.shift()); // Pega o primeiro da lista
console.log(desordenado.shift()); // Pega o segundo da lista
console.log(desordenado.shift()); // Pega o terceiro da lista
```

---

A função acima é baseada no algoritmo `Fisher-Yates shuffle` que consistem em colocar todos os elementos em um `array` e, de trás pra frente, permutar sua posição com algum elemento aleatório.

---

No caso do seu código a sugestão seria a seguinte:

```js
const maps = [{
    mapName: "dust ii",
    positions: [{
        posicao: "fundo",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "escuro baixo",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "base tr",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "base ct",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    mapName: "mirage",
    positions: [{
        posicao: "fundomirage",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
      {
        posicao: "escuro baixomirage",
        posicaoImg: "#",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const desordenados = {};

let selectElementMap = document.getElementById("mapSelector");

const desordenar = (arr) => {
  const copia = [...arr];

  for (let i = copia.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    const j = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));
    [copia[i], copia[j]] = [copia[j], copia[i]];
  }

  return copia;
};

function basicLogic() {
  const valueSelectedMap = selectElementMap.options[selectElementMap.selectedIndex].value;
  const desordenado = desordenados[valueSelectedMap]?.length ? desordenados[valueSelectedMap] :  desordenar(maps[valueSelectedMap].positions); // o array que será randomizado com base no <select> do usuario
  desordenados[valueSelectedMap] = desordenado;
  console.log(desordenado.shift()); // Pega o primeiro da lista
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <main class="content">
    <div class="selects-area">
      <select name="mapSelector" id="mapSelector">
        <option value="" disabled selected>Selecione um mapa</option>
        <option value="0">Dust II</option>
        <option value="1">Mirage</option>
        <option value="2">Cache</option>
        <!-- <option value="...">___</option> -->
      </select>
    </div>

    <button class="play" onclick="basicLogic();">Jogar</button>
  </main>
</div>
```

---

Referência: [**Shuffle an array**](https://javascript.info/task/shuffle).

Comment: Tentei utilizar essa resposta porém está retornando todos os elementos do array. A intenção é que a cada vez que o usuário clicar no botão, será selecionado uma posição de `maps[X].positions` aleatoriamente, e essa não poderá ser escolhida novamente. Aí quando clicar novamente o processo se repete.
A saída no console: `(4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]`

Comment: @GabrielG.Pereira então, depois de desordenar o array basta pegar um elemento por vez com a função pop() ou shift()

Comment: Então, aparentemente esse método tem uma boa chance de funcionar no meu código mesmo. O problema é que acabou sendo repetido uma posição (a `base ct`) do array também (algo que foi melhor que com o meu código, já que para selecionar todas as posições precisei clicar cerca de 9x).
No console.log fica dessa forma: [ConsoleLog] (https://prnt.sc/vrcds6)

Comment: @GabrielG.Pereira só repetiu se você implementou algo errado. Apresente todo o seu código usando essa solução que te digo o que está errado.

Comment: Não sei qual a melhor forma de enviar um código completo em respostas do StackOverflow, então coloquei no JSFiddle: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pkjx0L1o/)

Comment: Obrigado, o código funcionou como deveria!
Só queria perguntar uma coisa a mais: o que essa parte do código faz? `desordenados[valueSelectedMap]?.length ? desordenados[valueSelectedMap] :  desordenar(maps[valueSelectedMap].positions);`
No mais, agradeço sua ajuda.